# How do I plot multiple regression?

Tags: r, plot, linear-regression

I am using census data to regress incarceration, race, and gender on average weekly wages. My model is as follows:

```
model1 = lm(log_weekly_wage_incarc ~ incarc + race_black + race_white + female, 
            data = samp_ipums)
```

`incarceration`, `race_black`, `race_white`, and `female` are binary variables. `log_weekly_wage_incarc` is a continuous variable. How can I plot this?

Comment: Check out added variable plots, also known as partial regression plots. They are implemented in R in the `car` package: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/car/versions/3.0-5/topics/avPlots